# How to check for 2 of the same letters

Tags: python

If I have a list:

```
List=[1,2,3,4]
```

and i want to make a "if" that triggers if i have 2 X'es in List.

```
List[0] = "X"
List[1] = "X"
```

and then something like this:

```
if *2 "X" in List:
    print "i now have 2 X'es in List"
```

I can make `if "X" in List:`, but I want to make it so that it dose not do anything until I have 2 `"X"`. What I'm making is that I change the list by turning some into `"X"` but I want it to trigger if 2 of them are `"X"` and not 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `list.count()`:

```
if myList.count('X') == 2:
    print "count is 2"
```